# Javascript regex to validate if only numbers begins with leading zero

Tags: javascript, regex, input

I need to validate some inputs using a regex.

Here are some sample use cases and expected results.

If input contains letters it should match regex and if input contain 0 at beginning.

```
0001     - Matched
001      - Matched
01       - Matched
00.12312 - Matched
000.1232 - Matched
k0.0055  - Matched
0.15k    - Matched
kkkkk    - Matched
kk.15    - Matched
15k      - Matched
1        - Not matched
20       - Not matched
0.1      - Not matched
0.123123 - Not matched
```

What would a regex like this look like?

Comment: the last two contain zeroes at beginning, why should they not match?

Comment: Your question is unclear, and you have not shown us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Something like `/[a-zA-Z]|0[0-9]/`

Comment: Why does 0.123123 or 0.1 not match and 00.12312 - Matched?

Answer (score 1):

For your given inputs, regexp will be: `"^([0]{1,}[0-9a-z].*|.*[a-z].*)$"`

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function display() {
    input = ["0001", "001", "01", "00.12312", "000.1232", "k0.0055", "0.15k", "kkkkk", "kk.15", "15k", "1", "20", "0.1", "0.123123", "500"]
    result = ""
    for (i=0;i<input.length;i++){
          result += input[i] + " " + ((new RegExp("^([0]{1,}[0-9a-z].*|.*[a-z].*)$").exec(input[i]) == null) ? "Not Matched" : "Matched") + "<br/>"; 
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="display()">Display</button>

</body>
</html>
```

updated

Comment: When i testes input value 500 i got Matched. It should be Not matched.

Comment: How about regex that only allow to use one dot "." and input cannot have special characters like "* + - ; ' etc." Checking input like that ".........;[][]'" i get not matched.

Answer (score 1):

How about: `(^0\d+\.?\d*)|(.*[a-z]+.*)`

updated

Comment: When I tested input value 500 or 0.10000 I got Matched. It should be Not matched.

Comment: right. it's missing a `^`: `(^0\d+\.?\d*)|(.*[a-z]+.*)`

Answer (score 0):

Using **RegEx of @user8708 and @yarons which are perfect** and adding new condition by OP(hidden and late requirements) of including a dot "." excluding all other special characters.

```
^([0]{1,}[0-9a-z].*|.*[a-z].*|^\.+)$ //by @user8708 

(^0\d+\.?\d*)|(.*[a-z]+.*)|(^\.+$) //by @yarons
```

OP's unending requirement may also include

```
..... //To be matched
0.1....0 //To be matched
```